# MPS Typesystem Querying Databases/Issuing API calls

Tags: mps

I'm using MPS to implement a really interesting DSL.  What I'm curious to know, and haven't found anything on their site about, is whether I can, within the typesystem, issue an API call or query a database on the fly.  So we would see that an equivalence test occurs and I want to be able to issue an API call or database query to see the feasibility of that equivalence test under further constraints and analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any Java code but it will probably make the editor and possibly other parts of MPS unresponsive since asynchronous calls are not supported.

Comment: Yeah, I knew whatever it could do would end up being blocking; which is fine.  Just that I *can* make external requests is the important factor here.  Thanks!